# No fewer than VS at least

Tags: word-meaning

> The drag performer, whose real name is Tom Neuwirth, developed a consistent lead as voting progressed, and ended up with 290 points.
>   More than 50 points behind, The Netherlands came second with 238 points, with Sweden in third on 218.
>   The “bearded lady”, as the 25-year-old is known, had stirred controversy especially in some eastern European countries.
>   **But no fewer than** 13 countries gave her a maximum 12 points.

When saying **no fewer than 13** , does it mean **at least** ? 
Is it just about stylish writing ? Or they are somehow different?

Answer (score 2):

It is synonymous, but the expression "no fewer than" has a connotation of "and that's a lot".  So its use here is very similar to that if the sentence had been "a whopping *thirteen* countries gave her a maximum 12 points."